# The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have this seemingly simple linq-to-sql query that searches some data in several columns; something like this:

```
List<long> TheTableIDs = list of IDs (sometimes more than 2100)

var QueryOutput = (from x in TheDataContext.SomeTable

                   where TheTableIDs.Contains(x.ID) &&
                   
                   x.Col1.Contains(SomeString) || 
                   x.Col2.Contains(SomeString))

                   select x.ID).ToList();
```

The error I get is this:

> Additional information: The incoming request has too many parameters.
> The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of
> parameters and resend the request.

What's the best way to solve this?

I've looked around and a solution I found looks like this:

```
var QueryOutput = TheDataContext.SomeTable.AsEnumerable()

        .Join(TheTableIDs, x => x.LeadID, ci => ci, (x, ci) => x)

        .Where(x => SomeString.Contains(x.Col1) == true ||
                    SomeString.Contains(x.Col2) == true)
        
        .Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

This compiles and doesn't throw any exceptions but seems to ignore the `Where` clauses with `SomeString.Contains`

What's the solution to make this query work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simple - as long as TheTAbleID's contains less than 2100 ID's then - it is not legal to do that.

Cut the table into blocks of 2000 and then query each block separately, possibly in multiple threads.

Comment: What does it mean to "Cut the table" I don't understand.

Answer (score 15):

SQL doesn't support more than 2100 values in `in` statement, but you can use in with table with more than 2100 rows so you can insert your data into a table and change your query to check the `in` with selecting from that table

for example

```
Create TempIDs (bigint ID, uniqueidentifier guid)
```

guid column is for preventing mixing different user data

in your code

```
Guid myKey = Guid.New();
List<long> TheTableIDs = list of IDs (sometimes more than 2100)
TheDataContext.TempIDs.InsertAllOnSubmit(TheTableIDs.select(i => new TempIDs{ID = i, Guid = mykey});
TheDataContext.SubmitChanges();

var QueryOutput = (from x in TheDataContext.SomeTable

                   where TheDataContext.TempIDs.Contains(x.ID) &&

                   x.Col1.Contains(SomeString) || 
                   x.Col2.Contains(SomeString))

                   select x.ID).ToList();
```

also if you can retrive the ids from database , you can write a table value function in sql to return the ids and model this function in your code, let say its name is `fnGetIds`.
Then use it in your code as below

```
var QueryOutput = (from x in TheDataContext.SomeTable

                   where TheDataContext.fnGetIds().Contains(x.ID) &&

                   x.Col1.Contains(SomeString) || 
                   x.Col2.Contains(SomeString))

                   select x.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not an insert query.

Comment: @frenchie Yes In know, consider you have about 2500 values to check it in `in` so create a temp table insert all of 2500 items into that table and instead of `where column in (1,2,3,...,2500)` use `where column in (select val from temptable)` which has no limit on the number of values in `in`

Comment: I like and understand your solution. It'll work for some people; for me, I decided to split the list in chunks and execute multiple queries  in parallel using TLP because it seemed simpler using the code I already have. But I do like your approach; upvoted.

Comment: The problem with this approach is twice - first, you need a temp table, which is tricky in LINQ. Second - LINQ makes this 2500 inserts which is REALLY SLOW thanks to non-optimal SQL  VERY slow. THe soltuion would be to use SqlBUlkInsert, but that even more complex in code and away from LINQ. Yes, all that should be handled by EF transparently - sadly it is not.

Comment: @TomTom you are right about first approach but what about the second one (table value function), we are currently using this approach in our project

Comment: Good performance wise, bad in that it takes logic out of the C# layer. It is good if you do it like that, but it is a clumsy workaround. I jsut wish they would not be needed. Sadly they are. What I do not like is writing a server side tvf every time someone needs a list for a LINQ statement ;(

Comment: I would argue that there's no limit in the `IN` clause but rather in the number of parameters that can be passed. You can run a query with `IN (1, 2, ..., 2101)` but not `IN (@p1, @p2, ..., @p2101)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 where clauses:

```
List<long> TheTableIDs = list of IDs (sometimes more than 2100)

var _QueryOutput = (from x in TheDataContext.SomeTable
    where x.Col1.Contains(SomeString) || x.Col2.Contains(SomeString))
    select x.ID).ToList();

var QueryOutput = _QueryOutput.Where(w => TheTableIDs.Contains(w)).ToList();
```

For efficiency, you could refactor the code so it only does it this way if list contains more than 2000:

```
if (TheTableIDs.Count() > 2000)
   // Code Here
else
   // Code Here
```

Comment: Super super inefficient. If the number of records brought back with the IDs filter would be say 2500 but without the ID filter is say millions, you most definitely do not want to do this client side. There has to be a much better way to do on server side.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this and was I no way using 2100 parameters!  Something else was afoot.

On closer examination I found that I was adding supposedly 5 parameters in a loop, but the source object was not getting cleared, so the list of object to insert was just getting bigger and bigger.

```
 Dim reportNum = 1

                For Each report In wwo.wwoWeatherReport.listOfForecasts
                    'whack these into the  regionsAndCountries
                    db.addParameter("@forecastAirTemp" & reportNum, report.listOfhourlyForecasts(0).hourlyForecast_tempC)
                    db.addParameter("@forecastRainFall" & reportNum, report.listOfhourlyForecasts(0).hourlyForecast_precipMM)
                    reportNum = reportNum + 1

                Next
```

I had to Dim a new wwo object beforehand and it sorted it

```
Dim wwo As New wwwoManager

Dim reportNum = 1  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is using **Contains** which needs to be in a separate query:

```
List<long> TheTableIDs = list of IDs (sometimes more than 2100)

var QueryOutput = (from x in TheDataContext.SomeTable

                   where TheTableIDs.Contains(x.ID) 

                   select x.ID).ToList();

foreach(var s in QueryOutput){
   if(x.Col1.Contains(SomeString) || x.Col2.Contains(SomeString)){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a user-defined-table to pass in an array of data as a parameter.

Fairly straightforward in entity framework core:

```
 public IQueryable<Item> GetItemsByIds(IEnumerable<long> itemIds)
    {
                var items = this.DbContext.Items.FromSql(
                            GetCommand(),
                            GetParameters(itemIds));
    
                return items;
    }


 public static string GetCommand()
                    {
                        return $"EXEC CommandName @ItemIds";
                    }



 public static SqlParameter[] GetParameters(IEnumerable<long> itemIds)
                    {
                        var ids = new DataTable();
                        ids.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long));
    
                        foreach (var itemId in itemIds)
                        {
                            ids.Rows.Add(itemId);
                        }
    
                        var itemIdsParam = new SqlParameter("@ItemIds", SqlDbType.Structured)
                        {
                            Value = ids,
                            TypeName = "[ItemDbo].[udtID]"
                        };

                    var paramList = new List<SqlParameter>
                    {
                        itemIdsParam 
                    };

                    return paramList.ToArray();
                }
```

You have to of course create the UDT and stored proc in sql server first.

Comment: This is very interesting. Can you give an example of the store procedure? I have been looking for a way to return records via stored procedure given a set of filters. Your code `$"EXEC CommandName @ItemIds"`suggests that it can be done. I am interested to see sample code of `CommandName` stored procedure.

Comment: @Sam This video explains and demonstrates the concept perfectly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ewf5bivTKdI

Comment: Hi @iKnowNothing, the video you sent is for Table Valued Parameter. I know how to pass the value. But after the filtering, there will be a set of results. How do you return these results? TVP can only be passed to the stored procedure. But how do you return the filtered rows/records?

Comment: HI @Sam A select statement at the end of your stored proc should do the trick

Comment: Hi @iKnowNothing, say that the store procedure returns 100 records. I did the select statement, but how to get this 100 record out to my C#?

Comment: Hi @Sam The first code block in my answer shows this. You have to project it into a collection of the type you are returning. So you in your case items would be  List<record>, whatever record is

Answer (score -1):

Changed this query:

```
var z = (from b in db.GradeChangeHistories
    where m_list.Contains(b.SessionKey) 
    select b);
```

To this and it works:

```
var z = (from b in db.GradeChangeHistories        
    select b).ToList().Where(x => m_list.Contains(x.SessionKey));
```

Comment: This is really bad. It will bring **ALL** records from DB back before filtering out the unwanted records.