# Where In Clause error on The server support a maximum of 2100 parameters only

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently trying to try catch the insert SQL query from my simple C# application, but when i'm trying to insert the data into database with user id which is added into userIDList parameter, the error came out saying that

> The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports  a
>   maximum of 2100 parameters.

The userIDList sometimes will contains like 60 arrays above then the error will popped out.

My SQL CommandText will contain of

```
"SELECT * FROM TIME_ATTENDANCE_REPORT WHERE TRXDATETIME = @Date AND USERID IN (001,002,003,004,....)
```

So i think if more then certain number then the error popped out

Here are my sample code :

```
List<string> userIDList = new List<string>();
using (SqlCommand sqlDBComm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        openConnection();
                        SqlDataReader sqlDBReader;
                        sqlDBReader = null;
                        sqlDBComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TIME_ATTENDANCE_REPORT WHERE TRXDATETIME = @Date AND USERID IN (" + string.Join(",", userIDList) + ") ORDER BY USERID ASC ";
                        sqlDBComm.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                        sqlDBComm.Parameters["@Date"].Value = GetDateFrom;
                        sqlDBComm.Connection = sqlDB;
                        sqlDBComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        try
                        {
                            sqlDBReader = sqlDBComm.ExecuteReader();
                            t.Load(sqlDBReader);
                            sqlDBReader.Close();

                            if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                status = "Update";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                status = "Insert";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception errMsg)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error Code: " + errMsg.ToString());
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            sqlDBReader.Close();
                            closeConnection();
                        }
                    }
```

Any other solution can resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045912/the-incoming-request-has-too-many-parameters-the-server-supports-a-maximum-of-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

Instead of sending a list of IDs as seperate parameters, you can send a single @IDList parameter as a single comma separated string and let it parsed into IDs at the server side. Here is a function that I use for this (borrowed and modified from Jeff Moden's code):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[iSplitter] (@Parameter VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @splitResult TABLE (number INT, [value] INT)
AS
BEGIN
SET @Parameter = ','+@Parameter +',';

WITH cteTally AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@Parameter))
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Object_ID) AS N
            FROM Master.sys.All_Columns t1
            CROSS JOIN Master.sys.All_Columns t2
    )
INSERT @splitResult
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) AS Number,
    SUBSTRING(@Parameter,N+1,CHARINDEX(',',@Parameter,N+1)-N-1) AS [Value]
    FROM cteTally
        WHERE N < LEN(@Parameter) AND SUBSTRING(@Parameter,N,1) = ','
RETURN
END
```

With this function created once, I do it like:

```
sqlDBComm.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM TIME_ATTENDANCE_REPORT tar
    inner Join dbo.iSplitter(@UserIdList) ul on tar.USERID = ul.[value]
    WHERE TRXDATETIME = @Date
    ORDER BY USERID ASC ";
sqlDBComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserIdList",string.Join(",", userIDList));
```

This works very well for 5-6K integer ids but times out if used with 20-30K or more IDs. Then I created another alternative as a CLR procedure, and that one parses the list server side in less than a second. But I think this one is sufficient for your needs.

Another way is to send the IDs as an XML parameter and parse server side again.

Yet another way is to send a table parameter.

PS: Here is a [link that shows sample code for other ways](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/tr-TR/715c93c3-23ee-4f7b-af65-45eeb7d24865/checkboxlist-deki-seili-olan-itemlera-gre-arama-yapma-yardm?forum=csharptr). The site is in Turkish but the codes are crystal clear in C#, separate per approach.

EDIT: XML sample using Northwind Orders table:

```
void Main()
{
    int[] IDList = { 10265,10266,10267,10268,10269,10270,10271,10272,10273,10274,10275, 10320, 10400 };
    var idsAsXML = new XElement("IDS",
        from i in IDList
        select new XElement("Row", new XAttribute("Id", i)));

    string sql = @"
  DECLARE @hDoc int;
  DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Id int);
  exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML;
  INSERT @tbl 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, @Nodename, 1) WITH (Id int);
  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc;

  select * from Orders o
  where exists (select * from @tbl t where t.Id = o.OrderId) ";

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=Northwind"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XML", idsAsXML.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeName", "/IDS/Row");
        con.Open();
        tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }

    //tbl.Dump(); // linqPad luxury
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Table-Valued-Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it as a parameter. It requires you to create a new type in your database, and will enable you to pass an array to the query and let the database treat it as a table. If this is something you do a lot, it could come in handy.

I no longer have access to the project where I implemented this but everything is available in the [blog post](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). The code below is not tested, but I hope it can get you in the right direction.

**1.** Create a new type in your database:

```
CREATE TYPE integer_list_tbltype AS TABLE (n int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

**2.** Pass it as parameter:

```
sqlDBComm.Parameters.Add("@userIds", SqlDbType.Structured)
sqlDBComm.Parameters["@userIds"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
sqlDBComm.Parameters["@userIds"].TypeName = "integer_list_tbltype"
sqlDBComm.Parameters["@userIds"].Value = CreateDataTable(userIDList)
```

**3.** Method for creating the parameter:

```
private static DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<int> ids) {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("n", typeof(int));
    foreach (int id in ids) {
        table.Rows.Add(id);
    }
    return table;
}
```

**4.** Use it in your SQL:

```
... AND USERID IN (SELECT n FROM @userIds)
```

`CreateDataTable` from here:

[How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code)

Rest from here:

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#introduction